# configMap volume mount failure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, configmap

I've got a question, guys.

Any idea what would cause this sort of error.

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "PNIF-uid" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition.
```

The pod doesn't crash-loop by the way, which is what I expect to happen if one of the containers is unable to mount a configMap volume.

Comment: is it minikube or kubeadm or something else?

Comment: It's with Kubeadm.
Trying to mount the configMap as a volume and I get this warning when I run the kubectl describe pod command.

Comment: How is your API Server doing..any sign of heavy load?

Comment: Could a lot of load on the API server be responsible for this?

How do you determine how much load the API server might be under anyway?

Comment: you can check the API Server metrics exposed..a prometheus alert can be more helpful

Comment: Can you please share your YAML file so that it will be easy to understand the problem for others.

Comment: Hi, what is You cluster setup like? What k8s version how many master/worker nodes etc.

Comment: Would be helpful if you add more details.

Comment: I am currently having the exact same issue here